# sleep a while loop based on output from a function

Tags: shell, ksh

Need your help with the following. My .sh is as follows.

```
 getfunc (){

 if [condition 1]
 then
 echo "NOK" >flag
 else
 echo "OK" >flag
 fi
 }

 while IFS=" " read -r var1
 do
 getfunc
 if [ $flag -eq OK ]
 then
 "print 1"
 else 
 "sleep for sometime"
 fi
 done <file
```

I don't know how to tell while to keep trying in regular intervals, till it gets OK from getfunc.

Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Use a while loop with a flag variable to update the status

Comment: Hi big bounty, Sorry I don't get it. Can you please elaborate. thanks..

Comment: run a while loop and keep a flag variable that indicates whether the return value from getfunc() is OK. If it's OK, break from the loop or continue the loop. The test condition should be the flag variable

Comment: Ok got it, Thanks. But just asking is there an alternative method of doing it?

Comment: U can change while to do while or any other loop as such but the logic remains the same. It's because of the condition, until you get an OK from getfunc(). One improvement is return true or false instead of OK ,NOT OK

Comment: ok, Thanks bigbounty...

Comment: No problem, self learning is the best learning

Comment: Well said, until is even better. thanks..

Comment: until [[ condition ]]  do  echo "sleeping for 5 seconds"  sleep 5  done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  until [[condition]]
  do
  echo "sleeping"
  sleep 5
  done
```